# What are standardized and scalable methods to assess free recall?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, measurement, educational-psychology, long-term-memory

In cognitive psychology and education literature, free recall test is usually compared with recognition test (through multiple-choice questions) and the former is favored as a more reliable measure of learning. However, free recall test in college-level courses is not scalable and requires a lot of instructor's time.

I searched a lot and did not find any standardized method of measuring free recall in the literature. Most of them are relying on the subjective assessments of the instructors. The only convincing measurements that I was able to find, are:

- The adjusted ratio of clustering measure (ARC)
- Latent semantic analysis (LSA)
  These are both briefly explained in the method section of this paper: [Nestojko.Bui_.Kornell.Bjork_.2014.pdf (williams.edu)](https://sites.williams.edu/nk2/files/2011/08/Nestojko.Bui_.Kornell.Bjork_.2014.pdf)

What are other standardized and scalable methods to assess free recall?